# Finding the Inverse Laplace function.

Tags: laplace-transform, partial-fractions

I have been given $F (s)=\frac {2(3s^2+1 )}{(s^2-1)^3} $  and I want to find $  f (t) $ so that $L(f (t))=F (s) $. Can handle powers in denominator till $2$ but here they will go till $6$ . The only hint given is use exponentials for $\sinh (at),\cosh (at) $ but that doesn't seem very helpful to begin with. Also partial fractions seem very tedious. Is there any simple way to do it or even a simple partial fractions will help. Thanks!

Comment: The fact that$$\frac{2(3s^2+1)}{(s^2-1)^3}=\frac6{(s^2-1)^2}+\frac8{(s^2-1)^3}$$might be useful.

Comment: Did you use an app or you did it manually.?

Comment: I did it manually. In fact, what I did was to write $\frac{2(3x+1)}{(x-1)^3}$ as $\frac8{(x-1)^3}+\frac6{(x-1)^2}$ and I got this from the fact that $2(3x+1)=6x+2=6(x-1)+8$.

Comment: Thanks that solved it quite easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac {2(3s^2+1 )}{(s^2-1)^3} = 
\frac{K_1}{(s^2-1)^3} + \frac{K_2}{(s^2-1)^2} + \frac{K_3}{(s^2-1)} \tag{1}
$$

To find $K_1$, we multiply Eq(1) by $(s^2-1)^3$, we get

$$
2(3s^2+1 ) = 
K_1 + K_2(s^2-1) + K_3 (s^2-1)^2 \tag{2}
$$

In Eq(2), let $s=-1$, we obtain $K_1=8$.

To isolate $K_2$, we differentiate Eq(2) with
respect to $s$, we get

$$
2(6s) = K_2(2s) + K_3 4s(s^2-1) \tag{3}
$$

In Eq(3), let $s=-1$, we obtain $K_2=6$.

Again, we differentiate Eq(3) with respect to $s$ and $K_2=6$, we get

$$
\begin{align}
12 &= (6)(2) + K_3 4(3s^2-1) \\
12 &= 12K_3s^2 + 12 -4K_3 
\end{align}
$$

As a result, $12K_3=0 \rightarrow K_3 =0$ or $(12-4K_3)=12 \rightarrow K_3=0$.